# Гороскоп на javascript

Tags: javascript

Пожалуйста, помогите!

> Даны два целых числа: D (день) и M (месяц), определяющие правильную дату. Вывести знак Зодиака и гороскоп, соответствующий этой дате:
>
> - «Водолей» (20.1–18.2),
> - «Рыбы» (19.2–20.3),
> - «Овен» (21.3–19.4),
> - «Телец» (20.4–20.5),
> - «Близнецы» (21.5–21.6), «Рак» (22.6–22.7),
> - «Лев» (23.7–22.8),
> - «Дева» (23.8–22.9),
> - «Весы» (23.9–22.10),
> - «Скорпион» (23.10–22.11),
> - «Стрелец» (23.11–21.12),
> - «Козерог» (22.12–19.1).

**Добавлено.**

```
var dm = parseInt(prompt('Введите дату', 19.2));
if (dm < 20.1 && dm >= 18.2) {
    alert('Водолей')
} else if (dm < 19.2 && dm >= 20.3) {
    alert('Рыбы')
} else if (dm >= 21.3 && dm < 19.4) {
    alert('Овен')
} else if (dm >= 20.4 && dm < 20.5) {
    alert('Телец')
} else if (dm >= 21.5 && dm < 21.6) {
    alert('Близнецы')
}
...
```

Сделала по предыдущему примеру домашнего задания, но по-прежнему не выходит, для меня это новое, до сих пор понять не могу, что к чему. (((

Comment: И в чем сложность? За вас никто учебное задание решать не будет! Не получается - поможем, но нужны собственные наработки!

Comment: Пыталась, пробывала по разному, но так и не получается.

Comment: Где подтверждения, наработки кода?

Comment: Это уже просто лень! Я это задание на C делал, кстати, было тоже лень и нашел на javascript сделанное. Не погуглить что ли?

Comment: Подсказка: храните в разных переменных номер месяца и число! Будет что-то типа такого:  

    var d = 10;//10е число
    var m = 3;//3й месяц
    if((d >= 20 && m == 1) || (d < 18 && m == 2)){
        alert('Водолей');
    } else if(...){...}

Comment: Рекомендую "JavaScript+jQuery для начинающих в видеоформате"
http://1popov.ru/disc11/

Comment: Сейчас попробую, спс)))

Comment: Юлия, не слушайте их. Если хотите понять как это делается. Можете написать мне на Jabber, я попробую помочь.

Answer (score 3):

Намасте! Во имя наших индийских коллег я, слава Брахме, просветлился и нашел истинно правильный вариант с `switch` и `if`:

```
var den = parseInt(window.prompt('Введите день рождения'));
var mesyac = parseInt(window.prompt('Введите месяц рождения'));

/* ॐ */
switch (mesyac) {
    case 1:
        if (den <= 19)
            znak = 'Козерог';
        else
            znak = 'Водолей';
        break;
    case 2:
        if (den <= 18)
            znak = 'Водолей';
        else
            znak = 'Рыбы';
        break;
    case 3:
        if (den <= 20)
            znak = 'Рыбы';
        else
            znak = 'Овен';
        break;
    case 4:
        if (den <= 19)
            znak = 'Овен';
        else
            znak = 'Телец';
        break;
    case 5:
        if (den <= 20)
            znak = 'Телец';
        else
            znak = 'Близнецы';
        break;
    case 6:
        if (den <= 21)
            znak = 'Близнецы';
        else
            znak = 'Рак';
        break;
    case 7:
        if (den <= 22)
            znak = 'Рак';
        else
            znak = 'Лев';
        break;
    case 8:
        if (den <= 22)
            znak = 'Лев';
        else
            znak = 'Дева';
        break;
    case 9:
        if (den <= 22)
            znak = 'Дева';
        else
            znak = 'Весы';
        break;
    case 10:
        if (den <= 22)
            znak = 'Весы';
        else
            znak = 'Скорпион';
        break;
    case 11:
        if (den <= 22)
            znak = 'Скорпион';
        else
            znak = 'Стрелец';
        break;
    case 12:
        if (den <= 21)
            znak = 'Стрелец';
        else
            znak = 'Козерог';
        break;
}
window.alert('Знак зодиака: ' + znak);
```

(В лучших традициях индопогромирования, при некорректном вводе все просто упадет от ошибок.)

**Пояснение:**

Выше — очень плохой код. Он огромен, плохо поддерживаем (представьте усилия, которые потребуются, чтобы переименовать переменные в нормальные названия `month` и `day`, или использовать латинские названия знаков) и повторяет сам себя (каждый знак упомянут в коде два раза). Такой код приличные люди называют «индийским» и долго, нецензурно ругают.

*(Перенесено из комментариев)* На самом деле этот код — издевательство, которое долго писать, неудобно читать, сложно поддерживать, и работает он, вообще говоря, медленнее, чем вариант от Sh4dow (по крайней мере на V8 и JägerMonkey). Исключение по отношению производительности — Opera, но там с JS все плохо в принципе. Вот мерялка производительности: http://jsperf.com/hashcode-ru-30082-switch-vs-array-access — на результатах Browseroscope видно, что везде кроме Opera (которая сама по себе тормозная в этом плане) вариант со `switch` жестко проигрывает.

Поэтому присмотритесь к варианту от Sh4dow. Как видно, в каждом месяце есть только 2 знака зодиака. Это достаточно просто описать.

Для начала, Sh4adow создал массив из 13 элементов (по числу месяцев + 1). Каждый элемент списка — объект (здесь применяющийся как словарь, сравнимо, в *этом* применении, скажем, со структурами `record` в Pascal'е), с полями `name` и `d` (есть еще `m`, но оно не использовалось).

Зная месяц (от 1 до 12) мы получаем нужную запись. Элементы массива нумеруются, начиная с нуля, соответственно, обращаемся как `signs[m - 1]` (используем индексы 0 - 11). Если день в поле `d` меньше или равен нашему — нам нужен знак следующего «месяца». Именно поэтому там 13, а не 12 элементов — если мы смотрим декабрь, то `(m-1)+1 = 12` вышло бы за пределы индексов массива (0—11).

Стоит заметить, что можно было бы обойтись без этого, убрав 13-ю запись и написав `signs[m % signs.length]` (т.е. работая по модулю 13; 0—11 будут на своих местах, а 12 укажет на 0). Пожалуй, это было бы, даже правильнее — не нужно 2 раза повторять «Козерога.» Но так как сделано — тоже допустимо, это компромисс между кодом и данными — чуть больше данных, но чуть проще вычисления.

Далее, соответственно, мы знаем индекс записи (т.е. `m-1` или `m`) и все что остается — вывести название знака: `signs[...].month`. Что, собственно, и было сделано.

Comment: (Только не подумайте, что я рехнулся. Код, разумеется, писался не руками, а генерился по шаблону.)

Comment: Неужели нашелся хоть один здраво мыслящий человек? Насчет падения - естественно нужны проверке ПЕРЕД выполнением этого кода. Насчет месяца вроде бы в switch есть "default:". Еще можно дату одной строкой принять и разбивать перед этим кодом. На самом деле это самый оптимизированный код и самый здравый. Кстати для справки - те кто предлагал с делением: ваш код неверен т.к. не учитывает високосность. Вариант Sh4dow полностью оценить не могу, я не спец в js, только c++.

Comment: Разницы между JavaScript и C здесь нет, код будет таким же, почти знак в знак. Разве что объект, в силу отсутствия в C словарей или подобного типа, надо поменять на `const struct` с двумя полями (`name` и `d`; `m` не используется).

Если бы это было задание, подразумевающее использование `switch` — оно было бы оптимально именно с его использованием. А это не так. Вы же, как натренированная обезъянка, залипли в шаблоне «надо решать так», и решаете не поставленную задачу, а удовлетворяете мифическую волю некоего преподавателя. Это — не программирование.

Comment: И, да, про обучение. Перед программистом всю его карьеру, от юного быдлокодера до мудрого гуру, стоит задача — изучить проблему и постаратья найти ее оптимальное решение. Поэтому, если говорить о JavaScript (а не его ограниченном подмножестве), то этот код для обучения пригоден только в одном случае — если он написан обучающимся самостоятельно, в меру собственных знаний. Т.е. для обучения на ошибках и разборе (намеренно) плохих примеров. Но, ни в коем случае, не как код, показанный кем-то еще и представленный как правильный вариант решения («здесь необходимо использовать switch»).

Comment: Да, **`m`** я как-то на автомате вписал) Не учел, что он индексам равен будет.

Comment: 2drdaeman, абсолютно с вами не согласен. В обучении никогда не пихают массивы перед условиями. А это очень хороший пример для того чтобы пошевелить мозгами, чтобы правильно использовать switch, а не как тут предлогами массу вложенных if'ов.

Comment: >правильно использовать switch

А ничего, что он тут не нужен? В задании это не указано, поэтому действовать можно любым удобным способом.  
Кстати, после тонны комментов с критикой ответов хотелось бы увидеть ваше решение.

Comment: 2ling, прошу прощения, но полемику тут разводить не имеет смысла я уже написал все что я думаю и добавить больше нечего.

Comment: Вот и хорошо, что *добавить больше нечего*.

Answer (score 2):

```
Дата: <input id="f-day" type="text" size="2" />.<input id="f-month" type="text" size="2" /><br />
<input type="button" onclick="calcSign()" value="Посчитать" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var signs = [
  {name:'козерог', m:1, d:20},
  {name:'водолей', m:2, d:20},
  {name:'рыбы',    m:3, d:20},
  {name:'овен',    m:4, d:20},
  {name:'телец',   m:5, d:20},
  {name:'близнецы',m:6, d:21},
  {name:'рак',     m:7, d:22},
  {name:'лев',     m:8, d:23},
  {name:'дева',    m:9, d:23},
  {name:'весы',    m:10,d:23},
  {name:'скорпион',m:11,d:22},
  {name:'стрелец', m:12,d:21},
  {name:'козерог', m:13,d:20}
  ];
function calcSign() {
  var d = document.getElementById('f-day').value;
  var m = document.getElementById('f-month').value;
// BEGIN рабочий код
  if (signs[m-1].d <= d) {
    alert(signs[m].name);
    } else alert(signs[m-1].name);
// END рабочий код
  }
</script>
```

Честно говоря, юникс-таймстамп и цикл вообще растерзали мозг)

Comment: еще один человек пытается из пушки по воробьям...

Comment: Пушка - один IF-ELSE? o_O

Comment: это домашнее задание. неужели вы думаете что в таком задании будут функции?

Comment: 1) я не вижу метки "учебное-задание" и слов "домашнее задание" в вопросе. 

2) а почему нет-то? в школе JS - редкость, в универе, извините, пора бы уже и объекты с методами знать. Да и вообще учиться полезно.

3) а давайте вообще сделаем в ясли-стайле - на промптах и документ.врайтах + 13 if-else по 4 сравнения в каждом, тоже та еще оптимизация.

Comment: 1) Простите, но это задание должно даваться на 2-3м уроке.
2) Если вы не знаете простой способ - не следует писать сложным.

Comment: Хм, он кажется вам сложным?)) По-моему сложновато - это написать его в одно действие с созданием объекта на ходу и всем таким подобным. Но каждому свое, да. 

Кстати, ваш-то вариант где?

Comment: ну так это учебное задание) поэтому моего варианта тут нет) автору вопроса я уже все что мог подсказал. Предел комментов) продолжу тут) Меня ждете только вы) с автором вопроса я уже в личной беседе переговорил. но если вы так ждете моего варианта - дам подсказку. Есть 2 конструкции, которые решают эту задачу if и switch.

Comment: if switch ... что то мне напоминает..
http://forum.dklab.ru/perl/heap/OchistkaPamyatiPriPereboreMassivov.html

Answer (score 1):

```
//задаем массив соответвий название знака зодиака и количества дней в микросекундах 
var a = [
        ['козерог',1641600], // 22.12-01.01
        ['водолей',2592000], // 21.01-20.02
        ['рыбы',2419200], // 21.02-20.03
        ['овен',2592000], // 21.03-20.04
        ['телец',2505600], // 21.04-20.05
        ['близнецы',2678400], // 21.05-21.06
        ['рак',2592000], // 22.06-22.07
        ['лев',2678400], // 23.07-23.08
        ['дева',2592000], // 24.08-23.09
        ['весы',2505600], // 24.09-23.10
        ['скорпион',2505600], // 24.10-22.11
        ['стрелец',2419200], // 23.11-21.12
        ['козерог',864000], // 01.01-20.01
    ];

//день рождения в unixtimestamp
var birth = 175298400; // 1975-07-23

//поправка на февраль
a[2][1] += Math.floor((birth % 126230400)/31536000) == 2 ? 86400 : 0;

//вычисляем остаток
var ostatok = (birth % 126230400) % 31536000;

//перебираем массив а постепенно уменьшая остаток, таким образом когда остаток будет меньше количества дней в определенном знаке зодиака прерываем цикл
for(var v in a)  {
    if(ostatok <= a[v][1])
        break;
    ostatok -= a[v][1];
}
//выводим результат
alert(a[v][0]);
```

[еще варианты](http://otvety.google.ru/otvety/thread?tid=13549ed72dd761f0&pli=1)

[ссылка на оригинал](http://mabp.kiev.ua/2007/08/09/calculation_of_zodiacal_sign/)

Comment: Но ведь показывает неправильно и нужно, чтобы выводилось окно с вопросом "Введите дату?", но это я сделаю, но вот остальное как-то напутано(

Comment: Жуткий монстро-код. Это все делается через switch и if.

Comment: действительно недоглядел, была ошибка в коде, сейчас исправил, проверил всё работает.

Comment: @Сергей: Бред собачий. Через switch в языках, где нет возможности сопоставить с диапазоном (как есть в Ruby, Pascal, VB и др.), это не делается. В JavaScript такого функционала у switch нет. Через if это делается в школе для индийских специалистов. Как раз через задание интервалов — правильный DRY-подход. Вот, разве что, во имя юзабилити, нужно было бы сделать `var birth = +(new Date(window.prompt("Введите дату рождения (YYYY-MM-DD)")));`.

Comment: Мне кажется, что все кто отвечает на этот вопрос - индусы.

Answer (score 0):

Еще один индовариант. =)

```
var dm = prompt('Введите дату', '19.2'); // получаем дату
dm = dm.split('.'); // только нам надо ее "перевернуть", так как месяц более значим, чем число
dm = parseFloat(parseInt(dm[1])+'.'+parseInt(dm[0])); // перевернули, получили 2.19
if(dm < 1.20 || dm >= 12.23){alert('Козерог');} // перебираем
else if(dm >= 1.20 && dm <= 2.18){alert('Водолей');}
else if(dm >= 2.19 && dm <= 3.20){alert('Рыбы');}
...
```